# SSIS foeach container is skipping subfolders

Tags: ssis

I'm working on an SSIS package that receives a path from a parameter (then loaded into a variable that stays the same during all the execution) and loads all files (including subfolders) to a database. I'm doing this with a foreach file enumerator. The problem is that it's skipping a lot of the subfolders. This is the configuration it has. [image]

I already checked and there are, indeed, .txt files in the folders that it skips and the folders are not hidden.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the package is not hitting the main folder you think it is.  There is not enough information here to be sure.

Comment: Is the D drive a mapped network drive? If yes, try setting it to the fully qualified name (i.e., \\<DomainName>\<DirectoryPath>\

Comment: Where is the package executed (locally or on a server) and who is executing it (you or SQL Server Agent)?

Comment: Sorry, it's working well. I had to load 40 000 files and had to stop it somewhere in the middle of the process and it didn't load the files in order, so I thought it was skipping files. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for each enumerator doesn't loop through the files in order, so I thought it was skipping files.